# MongoDB aggregating timeseries data for charts

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use a MongoDB-collection for the first time to save my Internet of Things sensor data. By writing an API, I would like to extract data from MongoDB to represent these to the user in a chart.

My schema is as follows, with timestamp being a Linux timestamp and reading a float value of the entry.

```
var ReadingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    uuid: String,
    location: String,
    type: String,
    reading: Number,
    unit: String,
    timestamp: Number,
    battery: Number
});
```

Readings are saved frequently without specific intervals. Sensor A may send them every 10 seconds, while sensor B may send them every 5 minutes.

I would like to be able to extract data to plot a chart. I tried to group the intervals described by the following example: http://www.nrg-media.de/2013/10/mongodb-aggregation-group-by-any-time-interval/

But the results I am getting are `InternalError: too much recursion` or `The $subtract accumulator is a unary operator`.

I also found this solution, which matches my requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27751029/1765404. But the result is `InternalError: too much recursion` as well.

The reading schema may be changed if that would be helpful. The collection now consists ~70.000 rows of dummy data from the past month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now I actually moved from MongoDB to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com) thanks to the perfect handling of timeseries-data.